# "to be + V-ing / V-ed" Passive or Active?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Please read the following two sentences.

> 1) "We are concerned over this issue as the list seems **to be expanding** from drinks to foods"
>
> 2) "Samples have been taken **to be analyzed**"

Today, I found [this](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic77307.html) while I was searching for "to be + ing" pattern. The answerer says that first sentence is in active voice but I can't really understand why. It really seems like to be in passive voice. Could someone please teach me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the participle marks different constructions:

> *BE* + present participle is the active progressive.
>    The list is expand**ing**. ... The list seems to be expand**ing**.
>    We are analyz**ing** the samples. ... We will be analyz**ing** the samples.
>
> *BE* + past participle is passive.
>    The list has been expand**ed**.  ... The list seems to have been expand**ed**.
>    The samples have been analyz**ed**. ... The samples will be analyz**ed**.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "seems to" is a fixed expression after which an infinitive has to follow. So the (active) continious form "is expanding" is changed to "be expanding" (still active).