# Why "will" & Why "ed" is added to "include"? Can you paraphrase it please? Is subject eliminated?

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, inversion

> **Also included will be** any variations that have arisen from solar activity.

Comment: What is the "IT" referred to in the first sentence?  'it should be, etc."  Are these instructions about what an essay about the subject should include?

Comment: @Msfolly: "It" refers to the ideal "coverage".

Comment: I think so.The essay is general and about Variations in climate.

Comment: You can read the sentence as *"Any variations that have arisen from volcanic activity, solar activity, and, possibly, human activities will also be included."* Explaining why it works that way is a bit more difficult, but I think it's some kind of inversion. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28linguistics%29

Comment: @Damkerng oh now it seems understandable, yeah you're right, i think its inversion as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The author is using a **passive voice** in the passage. Using a passive voice does't always mention the subject explicitly which can be taken to be **the extent of climate change coverage** which **it** refers to.

**Also included will be** may hint that the researcher already has the data but has not finished the report, but this would be incidental. Using the **future perfect** indicates the author expects the inclusion to occur.

The phrase is a **throw away**, since without it, the understanding of the **enumeration** of factors is unchanged. However, the author may be using it for **emphasis** since certain natural but **intermittent** activities are listed afterwards **in contrast** to **continuous** processes which are mentioned before. **Lest we forget** could be used in place.

Additional information on **passive constructs** can be found [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26309/to-be-v-ing-v-ed-passive-or-active)

Your highlighted segment also has an **inverted** construction

> **Also included will be** any variations that have arisen from volcanic activity, solar activity, and, possibly, human activities.
>
> Any variations that have arisen from volcanic activity, solar activity, and, possibly, human activities **will be also included**.

both sentences are **equivalent without loss of understanding**, however the first one draws emphasis to additional factors to be included.

Comment: Much obliged @Peter. Although your answer was convincing and thorough, one part of it is still unclear for me. You mentioned "future perfect", does it mean that the sentence is future perfect? As Damkerng T said, the sentence could have been inverted. If it is so, Is the tense **future simple** rather than future perfect? Thank you in advance again.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorbakhsh [**Future simple**](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/future-1-will) is **will include**, [**future perfect**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect) is **will be included**. **Inversion** is independent of tense.  Thanks for accepting my answer, please up vote also

Comment: As you said, the sentence is passive and this fact makes the verb pp. So "will also be included" should be passive simple future, isn't it? future perfect is "subject+will+have+pp". i think if the sentence is passive future perfect it should be "will+have+been+pp", am I wrong?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorbakhsh You are not wrong.

Comment: Good effort, and it is a passive construction. But the current answer misses the fundamental grammar of the sentence as currently written. @Damkerng T. provides the most useful insight so far in his comment made 10 hours ago, under the question.

Comment: @JimReynolds The OP's original question is about tense, which is inversion independent, not construction, but I have added comments on **inversion** in my answer